# Finding Land Surface Temperature in/across 4 continuous images in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-8, mosaic, land-surface-temperature

I'm trying to find Land Surface Temperature of 4 continuous Landsat8 images in ArcMap 10.4. I was able to calculate them as individual panels (using these two videos as guidelines: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDQo2a5e7dM ;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwwXhMKo-yM), but that created nodata values that I couldn't eliminate.

My alternate approach was to create a mosaic of the images using composites of each image, but this leaves out bands 10 and 11, which I need to do the LSE calculations.

The concern I have with this is that all four images have different thermal band values/properties; if these bands don't make it into the mosaic in the way the images will, how can the calculation be done using ArcMap?